# UwAmp configuracion virtual host genera error 500 con .htaccess en la raiz del sitio

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

Tengo mi servidor local apache funcionando con UwAmp Portable en windows 7.
UwAmp es un proyecto generado a partir de Wamp server.

Al crear los virtual Host, estos funcionan correctamente.

Pero al incluir un archivo .htacces en la raiz del sitio, en la carpeta WWW, y tratar de ingrear
al virtual host creado, me genera el error 500 "Internal Server Error"

Al mirar el archivo log de errores me muestra esto:

[core:alert] [pid 2480:tid 924] [client 192.168.0.10:4231] C:/UwAmp/www/.htaccess: IndexIgnore not allowed here

Por el simple hecho de incluir cualquier linea en el .htacces inmediatamente se generara el error comnentado.

He buscado en varias partes, y no he logrado dar con la solucion.

Como se podria solucionar este problema ?

Este es el codigo utilizado para generar el virtual host, de dos formas distintas:

PRIMERA:

## UWAMP Generate Virtual Host

```
DocumentRoot "{DOCUMENTPATH}/ventas"
ServerName "ventas.con"
<Directory "{DOCUMENTPATH}/ventas">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes Indexes MultiViews 
</Directory>
```

SEGUNDA:

## UWAMP Generate Virtual Host

```
DocumentRoot "C:\UwAmp\www\ventas"
ServerName "ventas.con"
<Directory "C:\UwAmp\www\ventas">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes Indexes MultiViews 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de solucionarlo.

En el archivo http.conf incluir lo siguiente:

```
<Directory "C:\UwAmp\www">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride FileInfo Options
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```